# Handle search button on android keyboard - cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, extjs

I am trying to handle search button on android keyboard, so when it is pressed on a search field to start searching. 
I have handle the back button and volume down button but the search button on keyboard doesn't work in my case.
I have used the same example as it is in cordova documentation, back button and volume down works, the search button on keyboard doesn't work.
Any suggestion? does anyone have the same problem?

```
document.addEventListener("searchbutton", onSearchKeyDown, false);

 function onSearchKeyDown() {
    alert('search button');
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the solution that worked for me in case that someone else has the same problem like me. I used to handle the keyboard search button using extjs event

```
specialkey: function (field, e, event) {
      if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
           //search code 
       }
 }
```

that works for me in iOS(done button) and Android

Answer (score 0):

is searchbutton listener written after **onDeviceReady** event is fired?

Did you tried to insert `navigator.app.overrideButton("searchbutton", true);` before the `document.addEventListener("searchbutton", onSearchKeyDown, false);` method?

Comment: yes, it is after onDeviceReady. I have tried and  navigator.app.overrideButton("searchbutton", true); 
but i doesn't work. The solution for me was by handling the keyboard search button using extjs framework event 
specialkey: function (field, e, event)